# Variables in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I want to get the value defined in my Procedure as mentioned below.

```
declare
     city varchar2(50) := 'XYZ';
     TYPE table_type is table of table_name%rowtype;
     var table_type;

begin
     select * bulk collect into var from table_name;

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var(1).field); -- Output is City
```

I want the output of

```
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var(1).field); -- Output is XYZ
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: your code doesn't even run.  you are selecting INTO a variable that you have not declared.  Please update your post and present _working_ code that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: that code does not work, why are you using bulk collect for retrieving a variable ? just make a select into

Comment: I know, But it was written just to explain. In 1st row of table, 'City' is written under column 'field'. When I select that cell from table I get 'City'. But I want the value that is defined for city.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I've never been able to debug code that I cannot see.  It does no good to ask what's wrong with your code when you don't show the actual code that is causing the problem.

Comment: You have 2 answers coming at a result from different angles, but to both you reply "this is not i want to achieve". Well that says you have not explained what you want to achieve. Please revise your question and describe what you want is non-SQL terms.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code **does not work**. Second, if you are going to recover a variable, you don't need bulk collect

Example

```
create table mytest ( c1 varchar2(50) ;

insert into mytest values ( 'XYZ' );

commit;
```

Then

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
declare
     vcity mytest.c1%type := 'XYZ';
     var   mytest.c1%type;
begin
     select c1 into var from mytest where c1=vcity;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('vcity is '||vcity||' ');
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('var is '||var||' ');
end;
/SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
vcity is XYZ
var is XYZ

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

- **vcity** is just a variable defined with the type of the column c1, but
  assigned to a constant, in this case 'XYZ'
- **var** is the variable which I use to recover the value of c1 in the
  table, whatever that value is.

You don't need bulk collect here at all.

Comment: Thanks but this is not I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have several cities to list, you need to define a collection to house them once selected, then a variable of that collection.  So for example:

```
--setup 
create table table_name ( id   integer
                        , city varchar2(10) 
                        );
insert into table_name(id, city)
   select level, 'City #' || trunc(dbms_random.value( 10, 75 )) 
     from dual connect by level <= 10;
-- process 
declare
    type city_list is table of  table_name%rowtype; 
    var  city_list; 
begin

     select * 
       bulk collect 
       into var 
       from table_name;

     for r in 1 .. var.count
     loop
        dbms_output.put_line(var(r).city);  -- Output is City
     end loop; 
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, But this is not i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep remain mystery about why you want like this,
If I understood you , to achieve what you want you have to specify columns instead of '*' and replace the variable city with column field.

Dbfiddle link for your reference (unable to provide via link through mobile device)

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=20f1a1fff11d4acda7acc701ad120d32

```
DECLARE
  city varchar2(50) := 'XYZ';
  TYPE table1_type is table of table1%rowtype;
  var table1_type;
BEGIN
  select city,field2,field3,field4
    bulk collect into var 
    from table1;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var(1).field);
END;
/
```

Comment: @Deepak Sharma : out of curiosity asking, does it not fulfill your expectation ?